# OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.Image, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"

Tags: python, openai-api, streamlit

I am working on my own project to create a business card based on the information a user provides. I am using Streamlit and OpenAI to do this.

I keep getting this error:

> APIRemovedInV1: You tried to access openai.Image, but this is no
> longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at
> https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API. You can run
> `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the
> 1.0.0 interface. Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28` A detailed migration
> guide is available here:
> https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

This is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import openai
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

# Set up your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Function to calculate the brightness of an image
def calculate_brightness(image):
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray_image = image.convert("L")
    # Calculate average pixel brightness
    brightness = np.mean(np.array(gray_image))
    return brightness

# Function to determine text color based on brightness
def get_text_color(background_image):
    brightness_threshold = 127.5
    brightness = calculate_brightness(background_image)
    if brightness < brightness_threshold:
        return "white"
    else:
        return "black"

# Function to generate logo image based on organization name
def generate_logo_image(organization_name):
    # Split organization name into words
    words = organization_name.split()
    # If organization name has more than one word, take the first letter of each word
    if len(words) > 1:
        logo_text = "".join(word[0] for word in words)
    # If organization name has only one word, take the first letter
    else:
        logo_text = organization_name[0]

    # Define font and size for logo
    logo_font_size = 64
    logo_font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", logo_font_size)  # Use a bold font for the logo

    # Create a blank white image for the logo
    logo_image = Image.new("RGB", (logo_font.getbbox(logo_text)[2], logo_font.getbbox(logo_text)[3]), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(logo_image)

    # Calculate text position to center the logo
    text_x = (logo_image.width - draw.textlength(logo_text, font=logo_font)) / 2
    text_y = (logo_image.height - logo_font_size) / 2

    # Add text to the logo image
    draw.text((text_x, text_y), logo_text, fill="black", font=logo_font)

    return logo_image

# Function to generate business card image
def generate_business_card(name, designation, contact_number, email_address, logo_image, background_image):
    # Create a blank white image
    card_width, card_height = 3.5 * 300, 2 * 300  # Standard business card size: 3.5 x 2 inches at 300 DPI
    business_card = Image.new("RGB", (int(card_width), int(card_height)), "white")

    # Add background image if provided
    if background_image:
        business_card.paste(background_image, (0, 0))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(business_card)

    # Determine text color based on background image brightness
    text_color = get_text_color(background_image)

    # Add logo image to the header
    if logo_image:
        logo_width, logo_height = logo_image.size
        logo_x = (card_width - logo_width) / 2
        logo_y = 20
        business_card.paste(logo_image, (int(logo_x), int(logo_y)))

    # Define font and size for text
    font_size = 36
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", font_size)  # Use a bold font

    # Define contact information
    contact_info = f"{name}\n{designation}\n{contact_number}\n{email_address}"

    # Calculate text width for contact information
    contact_text_width = max(draw.textlength(line, font=font) for line in contact_info.split("\n"))

    # Add contact information to the card
    contact_text_x = (card_width - contact_text_width) / 2
    contact_text_y = (card_height - font_size * 4) / 2
    draw.multiline_text((contact_text_x, contact_text_y), contact_info, fill=text_color, font=font, align="center")

    return business_card

# Define Streamlit app
def main():
    st.title("Business Card Generator")

    # Input fields for user information
    name = st.text_input("Enter Name:")
    designation = st.text_input("Enter Designation:")
    contact_number = st.text_input("Enter Contact Number:")
    email_address = st.text_input("Enter Email Address:")
    organization_name = st.text_input("Enter Organization Name:")

    # Generate logo image based on organization name
    if organization_name:
        logo_image = generate_logo_image(organization_name)
    else:
        logo_image = None

    # Prompt for background image generation
    st.header("Background Image Generation")
    background_prompt = st.text_area("Provide a prompt for the background image generation:")

    # Button to generate business card
    if st.button("Generate Business Card"):
        if name and designation and contact_number and email_address:
            # Generate background image
            if background_prompt:
                background_response = openai.Image.create(prompt=background_prompt)
                background_image = Image.open(background_response.url)
            else:
                background_image = None

            # Generate business card image
            business_card_image = generate_business_card(name, designation, contact_number, email_address, logo_image, background_image)

            # Display business card image
            st.image(business_card_image, caption="Business Card", use_column_width=True)

# Run the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried fixing my code based on the resources I found online, which is the [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742) from which I understood that there have been major changes, and `openai.Image.create()` to  `client.images.generate()` is one of them.

I tried fixing my code in relation to this, but I lost the whole flow, so I had to revert it back to the base code I worked on, which I have added in the post.

Can anyone please guide me with my issue? I know I am almost there, but yet I feel I am too far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is for getting answers for questions, not for guiding someone through an uplift in a continuous back and forth. You might want to join one of the (presumably many) openai tool user groups/discords/etc. instead. And if following the official documentation does not help, then you should probably file a docs update request (if that option exists) because if you're having trouble, so will others, and getting the docs update will benefit the most people.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you have the OpenAI Python SDK >=`v1`, but you're trying to use the code that works with the <=`v0.28`.**

**OPTION 1: Migrate your code**

Run `openai migrate` which will change your code so that it is compatible with >=`v1`. Basically, what this will do is change the method name from this...

```
openai.Image.create
```

...to this.

```
openai.images.generate
```

Of course, you can change this part of the code manually as well. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/images/create?lang=python).

**OPTION 2: Downgrade your OpenAI Python SDK**

Downgrade the OpenAI Python SDK to `v0.28` and leave the code as is.